# Set default props for one property of an object

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to set default props for a component that gets an object. The problem is that I need the default prop to apply to the missing property of the object, but it only works when the whole object is not set:

```
const App = ({data}) =>{
    return(
        <div></div>
    )
}

App.defaultProps = {
    data : {
        C : "blah"
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    data : PropTypes.shape({
        A : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        B : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        C : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }).isRequired
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It won't be merged recursively, you'd be better off setting that default when you get values *from* props, e.g. `const { data: { C = "blah" } } = this.props;`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  that makes sense, i was curious to find out if there is another way around. thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultProps` doesn't merge the value but instead replaces it. In order to get around this, you can simply do this operation in the render itself

```
const App = ({data}) =>{
    const newData = Object.assign({}, { C : "blah" }, data);
    return(
        <div></div>
    )
}
```

and use it by the name `newData`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! A nice and readable solution would be:

```
const App = ({data}) =>{
    const defaultData = { C: "blah" }
    const newData = {...defaultData, ...data}
    return(
        <div></div>
    )
}
```